# idempotent functions in the space of continuous functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, continuity

*Question.* $X$ is a connected iff the zero and identity functions are the only idempotent function in $C(X)$.

*Answer.* If $f\in C(X)$ is idempotent then $f(x)^2=f(x),\ \forall x\in X $, 
then $f(x) =0 $ or $1$ which implies Im($f$) is a subset of $\{0,1\}$.

Let $X$ be connected. Then Im($f)=\{0\}$ or $\{1\}$ hence $f$ has two choices: the zero function or the identity function.

How to prove the reverse part and are my above arguments true?

Comment: For the reverse conclusion: Assume $X$ is not connected and consider the indicator function for a connected component.

Comment: Isn't "identitiy function" a bad name for $X\to\mathbb R, x\mapsto 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more conceptual proof: Establish a bijection between the idempotent elements of $C(X)$ (i.e. $\{0,1\}$-valued continuous functions) and the clopen subsets of $X$. It maps a clopen subset $C \subseteq X$ to its characteristic function. This is very simple: Use the known bijection between functions $X \to \{0,1\}$ and subsets of $X$, and observe that a function is continuous iff the corresponding subset is clopen.